# Problem transfer list Localite to Add User in a selectBox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Good morning all,

Here I am starting in vue.js and I get stuck on a point that does not seem complicated.

Indeed, I try to pass my list of localities, in my adduser component. So that when creating the user he has to select localities.

But impossible to pass the list to him yet I know that it is necessary to use the props but I can not.
Can you help me ?

Thank you

Component Add user :

```
<template>
  <div class="submitform">
    <div v-if="!submitted">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nom">Nom</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom" required v-model="utilisateur.nom" name="nom">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prenom" required v-model="utilisateur.prenom" name="prenom">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="profession">Profession</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="profession" required v-model="utilisateur.profession" name="profession">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="adresse">Adresse</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adresse" required v-model="utilisateur.adresse" name="adresse">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" required v-model="utilisateur.email" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="login">Login</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" required v-model="utilisateur.login" name="login">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" required v-model="utilisateur.mobile" name="mobile">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">password</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" required v-model="utilisateur.password" name="password">
        </div>
        <!--<div>
        <ul>
                <li v-for="(localite, index) in localites" :key="index">
                                                {{localite.ville}}
                    
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>-->
        <!--<div>
        <select>
          <option v-for="(localite, index) in localites" :key="index">
            {{localite.ville}}
          </option>
        </select>
        </div>-->

        <button v-on:click="saveUtilisateur" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
    
    <div v-else>
      <h4>You submitted successfully!</h4>
      <button class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="newUtilisateur">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import http from "../http-common";
import Localite from "../components/LocalitesList.vue"
export default {
  name: "add-utilisateur",
  data() 
  {
    return {
      utilisateur: {
        id: 0,
        nom:"",
        prenom:"",
        profession:"",
        adresse:"",
        email:"",
        login:"",
        mobile:"",
        password:"",
        actif: 0,
        localite: 0
      },
      Localite: [],
      submitted: false
    };
  },
  components:
  {
    'localite': Localite
  },

  methods: 
  {
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
    saveUtilisateur() {
      var data = {
        nom: this.utilisateur.nom,
        prenom: this.utilisateur.prenom,
        profession: this.utilisateur.profession,
        adresse: this.utilisateur.adresse,
        email: this.utilisateur.email,
        login: this.utilisateur.login,
        mobile: this.utilisateur.mobile,
        password: this.utilisateur.password,
        localite: this.utilisateur.localite
      };
      http
        .post("/utilisateur", data)
        .then(response => {
          this.utilisateur.id = response.data.id;
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
      this.submitted = true;
    },
     /*   retrieveLocalites() {
      http
        .get("/localites")
        .then(response => {
          this.localites = response.data; // JSON are parsed automatically.
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },
    refreshList() {
      this.retrieveLocalites();
    }
    /* eslint-enable no-console */
  },
  /*mounted() {
    this.retrieveLocalites();
  }*/
    /* eslint-enable no-console */
  
};
</script>

<style>
.submitform {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
```

Component Localite:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="this.localite">
    <h4>Localite</h4>
    <div>
      <label>CP: </label> {{this.localite.cp}}
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Ville: </label> {{this.localite.ville}}
    </div>

    <span class="button is-small btn-danger" v-on:click="deleteLocalite()">Delete</span>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <br/>
    <p>Please click on a Localite...</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import http from "../http-common";

export default 
{
  name: "localite",
  props: ["localite"],
  methods: 
  {
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
    
    deleteLocalite() {
      http
        .delete("/localite/" + this.localite.id)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.$emit("refreshData");
          this.$router.push('/localite');
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
    /* eslint-enable no-console */
  }
};
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Resolved :) Andreasrein solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Props are used to pass data down in the component hierarchy. If you want to get data from an API and pass it to several components I would suggest getting the list of Localite's in a parent component and then pass it via props. A rule of thumb is to have more logic in parent components and less logic in child components.

Example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <localite :localite="listOfLocalites" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Then you can in your localite component get the the prop via `props: ["localite"]`